# VBA Equivalent of Sizeof()?

Tags: c++, vba, sizeof

Is there an equivalent of the `C++` `sizeof` function in VBA?

The only remotely similar functions seem to be the `Ubound` and `LBound` operators on arrays.

```
Dim arr(1 to 4) as integer
MsgBox Ubound(arr)
```

But this is not really the same thing as the C++ code:

```
int arr[10];
std::cout << sizeof(std::string) << "\t" << sizeof(arr);
```

Comment: What would you use this information for in VBA? I cannot imagine a non-contrived use case.

Comment: @delnan In looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320127/parse-data-in-multidimensional-vba-array I intended to answer with a comparison showing how little memory the array was actually using. However, I realized I was not able to evaluate this (without simply finding the memory allocation for a `Variant` and manually calculating this).

Comment: @enderland There is no such thing as memory "actually used" by an array. Array uses as much memory as it was declared to. Number of elements in a dimension is `ubound(arr, d) - lbound(arr, d) + 1`, where `d` is a 1-based dimension number.

Comment: there is a list within the developer help - that's about the closest I can find: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(v=VS.60).aspx

Comment: As an equivalent of `SizeOf()`, there would be the **[Len Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445063(v=vs.60).aspx)** but with strings it will not work as `SizeOf` because it will literally check the length of the string contained in a string variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The few pointer-related functions that can be used in VBA are at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199824 No obvious equivalent of `sizeof` though

For an array, you could potentially do something with `VarPtr` if you temporarily made the array one item longer and then shrank it back to the desired size:

```
Sub foo()

Dim arr() As Integer 
Dim i As Integer

ReDim arr(1 To 5)
arr(1) = 12
arr(2) = 456
arr(3) = -41
arr(4) = 17

Debug.Print VarPtr(arr(1)) & "; " & VarPtr(arr(5)) & "; " & VarPtr(arr(5)) - VarPtr(arr(1))

ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 4)

End Sub
```

Comment: I get this output - 
528088544; 528088552; 8 - how is this showing me any meaningful information?

Comment: Your output shows that the first element of the array starts at location 528088544 and the fifth element starts at 528088552. The difference between those locations is 8 bytes and this (obviously) represents the size occupied by 4 integers. Therefore, each integer occupies 2 bytes. You could achieve the same result with a two entry array or any array size larger than one

Comment: Good answer but you could use LBound and UBound (instead of 1 and 5) to genericize.

Comment: Don't subtract two `VarPtr` directly unless you want to end-up with an unexpected number or overflow. `VarPtr` returns a signed integer while addresses are unsigned.

Comment: @ Florent B.: so what's the correct workaround?

Answer (score 6):

I realise this is super late, but... What you want is `LenB()`

```
Public Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Debug.Print LenB("a") '==>2 i.e. ["a",0&]

Dim r as RECT
debug.print LenB(r) '==>16 i.e. 4 bytes for each long
```

Comment: Doesnt work for excel sheets.  'Object doesn't support this property or method'  :(

Comment: @johnktejik Objects are pointer sized, i.e. the size of a LongPtr. 8 on 64 bit systems and 4 on 32 bit systems.

Answer (score 2):

There would be the **[Len Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445063%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)** but with strings it will not work as `SizeOf` because it will literally check the length of the string contained in a string variable.

So to check the byte size of an array of ints:

```
Dim arr(1 To 4) As Integer
Debug.Print (UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1) * Len(arr(LBound(arr)))
```

Immediate window will show:
`8`

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: @enderland; I think it is now.

Comment: This works only for arrays of uniform data type, such as Integer in this case.  For a Variant array with a possible mix of array element types, see barrowc's post, above.

Answer (score 0):

As defined in [VBA Reference Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/len-function).

You can use `LEN` or `LENB`

---

**Example of `LEN`**

```
Type CustomerRecord    ' Define user-defined type.
    ID As Integer    ' Place this definition in a 
    Name As String * 10    ' standard module.
    Address As String * 30
End Type

Dim Customer As CustomerRecord    ' Declare variables.
Dim MyInt As Integer, MyCur As Currency
Dim MyString, MyLen
MyString = "Hello World"    ' Initialize variable.
MyLen = Len(MyInt)    ' Returns 2.
MyLen = Len(Customer)    ' Returns 42.
MyLen = Len(MyString)    ' Returns 11.
MyLen = Len(MyCur)    ' Returns 8.
```

---

**Example of `LENB`**

```
Function LenMbcs (ByVal str as String)
    LenMbcs = LenB(StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode))
End Function

Dim MyString, MyLen
MyString = "ABc"
' Where "A" and "B" are DBCS and "c" is SBCS.
MyLen = Len(MyString)
' Returns 3 - 3 characters in the string.
MyLen = LenB(MyString)
' Returns 6 - 6 bytes used for Unicode.
MyLen = LenMbcs(MyString)
' Returns 5 - 5 bytes used for ANSI.
```