# Is there a way to display or to view the memory allocated or usage of an array in Excel-VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, memory-management

I want to see the memory usage of a specific array in my code. It seems that this Global array causes lots of usage in my memory. It also causes our code to have Run Time Error. The RTE problem was solved when we erase that specific array. On the other hand, we want to monitor the memory usage of this array for documentation.

We try to monitor the memory, but it is for the whole application, by using task manager.

I expect to get or display the allocated memory for that specific array for monitoring.

**Sample Simplified Code:**

**Global Declaration:**

```
Public array_double(1 to 12) as New Double
```

**Inside Local Function**

```
For s = 1 To 8
    For i = 1 To 12
            array_double(i) = 0#
    Next i

    For r = 1 To 64
        For i = 1 To 12
                array_double(i) = array_double(i) + some_value_double
        Next i
    Next r     
Next s
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the array storing - objects, ordinal types or strings? I think the following question and possibly answers might be of help: [VBA Equivalent of Sizeof()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321404/vba-equivalent-of-sizeof)

This is the code I test with in Excel 2003:

```
Public array_double(1 To 12) As Double

Sub test()
  For s = 1 To 65535
    For i = 1 To 12
      array_double(i) = 0#
    Next i

    For r = 1 To 64
      For i = 1 To 12
        array_double(i) = array_double(i) + 1
      Next i
    Next r
  Next s
  Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

After several runs my Mem Usage column in task manager for the Excel.exe process stays at 24MB.

My assumption is the leak the OP is detecting is somewhere else not with the array.

Comment: Hi Ivo, all of the elements inside the array is double.

Comment: The double type is 8 bytes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/double-data-type). Multiplying 8 by the length of the array should result in a relatively close estimation as to the memory required to hold the array. The VarPtr result for the last minus VarPtr of the first element will probably give the same result.

Comment: Here's a simplified concept of my code, the array_double is a Global Variable. Does the multiple loops affects the memory usage even it is just overwriting the array? I've edited my summary for the sample simplified code, kindly use it as reference. Thanks.

Comment: And the global array_double is of length 13? Are you using base 0 or 1 for the array? Can you also post the declaration of the global array_double.

Comment: Here's the declaration:
        Public array_double(1 to 12) as New Double

Comment: What Excel version? Mine old one (2003) with 64k iterations of the outer "s" loop uses the same amount of memory in task manager, does not move at all. Also the declaration I use is Dim array_double(1 To 12) As Double. The one provided yields a compile error.

Comment: My Excel version is 2003. The Global declaration is inside a module. Does yours outputs large scale in memory?

Comment: Updated my answer. I put the code in a module in the same workbook. Anyway I was not able to declare the array as "New" Double.